# Update spring boot datasource properties on application startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

How can I load the datasource connection properties for spring boot JPA application dynamically on server startup.
e.g

`datasource.url=${dynamicUrl}
 datasource.username=${dynamicUsername}
.....`

I want to do this as my connection configuration is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this article [24. Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), if you are developing a @Component that uses a name property:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.*
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*

@Component
public class MyBean {

    @Value("${name}")
    private String name;

    // ...

}
```

For one-off testing, you can launch with a specific command line switch (e.g. java -jar app.jar **--name="Spring"**).
Therefore, you can dynamically configure the connection parameters while running your application.